# Load bean once throughout test suite

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I have a bean that describes my session factory. I only want to load this bean once throughout my entire test suite. I wanted to know, is this possible? And I would like to localize to my `context.xml` if that is possible too. I can post any source you want, just ask.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring test framework, if all test case classes use the same `locations` attribute, the context is preserved between runs. In the example below context defined in `context.xml` will be loaded only once (before first test case) and will be closed when JVM exits:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:context.xml")
@Transactional
public class FooTest {
  //...
}

@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:context.xml")
@Transactional
public class BarTest {
  //...
}
```

You cannot preserve only one bean, but you can load the whole context once. See my article [*Speeding up Spring integration tests*](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2010/12/speeding-up-spring-integration-tests.html).

Comment: Yes I have this part. But even though the context is preserved, every bean still gets loaded. Pardon my ignorance, but what good is preserving the context if every bean still needs to get loaded?

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c: beans are loaded when context is created. If the context is preserved across test cases, all beans created within that context are reused. Are you sure you are following the pattern above? I know from experience that if all XML file locations are the same, context (and all beans) is loaded only once.

Comment: I have done this and it appears my beans are still being loaded. I see `DEBUG  DefaultListableBeanFactory | Creating instance of bean 'sessionFactory' on all of my test cases`. Even using these annotations. And i always see `Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'sessionFactory'`

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c: how are you running your tests? Via Eclipse? maven? Make sure they all run in one JVM invocation (contexts are cached using `ThreadLocal`

Comment: Through an ant build using intelliJ.

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c: in `ant.xml` set [`forkmode`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) to `once`. Maybe IntelliJ allows overriding it in GUI.